# VMWare Remote Console not showing any GUI Dialog on MacOS Mojave

Tags: vmware, remote-host

Installed VMWare Remote Console 10.0.4 (latest as of writing this) on MacOS Mojave 10.14.3. installation went well, but running the app, nothing is shown on the Mac. seen some unanswered similar questions on VMWare forum [here](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/573777) and added my question [here](https://communities.vmware.com/message/2851003#2851003). Have anyone seen the same issue and have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I may have sound something - when i go to a vSphere VM, i have two options: 'Launch Web Console' or 'Launch Remote Console' - if i click the latter, i get the application to open with the UI displaying as it should. so, unlike VMWare Horizon, Player and others, here it seems you need to connect to the VM first via browser, to open the desktop client. weird choice from VMware in my mind, but still some solution. See image below
[image]